# Angular 1: ng-repeat throws infdig error

Tags: angularjs, httprequest, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-infdig

**Controller:**

```
(function(angular) {

    var app = angular.module('t2w');

    app.factory('httpq', function($http, $q) {
        return {
            get: function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get.apply(null, arguments).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.resolve);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    });

    app.controller('JobsCtrl', ['$scope','httpq','baseUrl', function($scope, httpq, baseUrl) {

        httpq.get(baseUrl + '/jobs/json').then(function(data) {
            $scope.jobs = data;
        }).catch(function(data, status) {
            console.error('Error', response.status, response.data);
        }).finally(function() {
        });

        $scope.random = function() {
            return 0.5 - Math.random();
        };
    }]);

})(window.angular);
```

**View:**

```
...

<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="job in jobs | orderBy:random">
        <td class="jobtitle">
            <a href="#jobs/{{job._id}}">
                {{job.title}} m/w
            </a>
            <p>
                {{job.introText | limitTo: 150}}...
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{job.area}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

...
```

**JSON Response:**

```
{
    "_id": "5880ae65ff62b610h4de2740",
    "updatedAt": "2017-01-19T12:17:37.027Z",
    "createdAt": "2017-01-19T12:17:37.027Z",
    "title": "Job Title",
    "area": "City",
    "introText": "Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor",
    ...
}
```

**Error:**

> angular.js:13920 Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

Can someone give me a hint why I get this error? Already checked the documentation and I do not call a function in my ng-repeat nor generate a new Array with each call.

Comment: can you show `$scope.jobs` value?

Comment: I think it throws error because `random` is actually a function. Try it without `orderBy`

Comment: $scope.jobs = 
Array(20)
  0: Object
  1: Object
  2:Object ...
...

Comment: @KonradKahl Yes, you are right. *random* causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to resolve the problem is to sort the Array randomly in the controller and not in the view:

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array;
}

$scope.jobs = shuffle($scope.jobs);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want `ng-repeat` to sort data randomly you will have to apply your own filter like this:

```
.filter('shuffle', function() {
    return function(ary) {
        return _.shuffle(ary);
    }
});
```

next use it in view like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat='job in job | shuffle'>
```

Comment: Still throws `[$rootScope:infdig]` with this filter.

Comment: I guess that the problem is, that I have a single Array with multiple objects. So thats why the shuffle filter solution is still not working.